# Sufi Number Square

Tags: mathematics, real

Years ago I was gifted a copper number square by a Sufi mystic. I have puzzled over its significance for all these years and still haven't been able to find a suitable answer. The number square is a 3x3 grid of values as follows:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
4&9&6\\\hline
5&3&1\\\hline
18&16&11\\\hline
\end{array}
$$

All the values add up to the prime number 73.
The Sufi mystic who gifted this to me frequently practiced numerology. The answer may lie there - so I suggest reading up on the mathematics of numerology if you are unfamiliar with it.

I appreciate any assistance that you may be able to give me!

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what a "copper number square" is, and neither does google, can you explain or would that give away the answer?

Comment: To be completely honest I don't know what the copper number square is. It is similar in design to a "Magic Number Square", but doesn't conform to the rules. I do know that there is a meaning here, but I really cannot attest to the solution. I really was given this square by a Sufi mystic, and it really is made out of copper. It's 1.5" x 1.5" and I keep it in my wallet. Supposedly it is for protection - energetic?

Comment: Were these numbers originally given as we see them now, or were they in some other system of writing? (e.g. Roman numerals)

Comment: Is it possible to add a picture of it?

Comment: I can probably add a picture of it shortly. It looks exactly as pictured above - no translation necessary. Thank you to those who formatted the square correctly I really appreciate that. I believe that the answer is based upon numerology - for example, adding all the horizontal rows via numerology principles yields (from top to bottom) 1, 9, 9. Adding the vertical rows (left to right) yields 9, 1, 9. The diagonals also equate to 9 and 9. I believe the significance to reside here, but it may require a deeper understanding of Sufi mysticism or mathematics that I am lacking. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did this mystic know you personally?  Numerology often has to do with your name and/or birthdate; could this square have been specially constructed for you, or is it something more general?

Comment: It was not cast specifically for me, no.

Comment: this looks promising: http://www.jainmathemagics.com/ebookofmagicsquaresv2/

Comment: Is it possible the numbers are all Qoran quotes?

Comment: Is it possible the square is actually an incomplete order-4 or order-5 square as opposed to an order-3 square?

Comment: How the sum is 73?

Comment: Sum of all the numbers present here is 73. 
First of all I think you might be confusing religious artifact with some mathematics problem. I still can't figure out exactly what you want to know: why are the adding up to 73 (which turns out to be prime) or why are they arranged in this particular manner. Please elaborate your meeting with this sufi mystic as in what exactly was your conversation.

Comment: It sounds like a standalone talisman that doesn't represent part of a larger square. You might get some more useful answers if you ask this question on Islam.SE. The top line, read left to right because it is numerical, probably corresponds to the Arabic letters dal ta waw, although in Arabic numerology there are not usually single letters that correspond to 18, 16 and 11. [This](http://www.muslimphilosophy.com/ik/Muqaddimah/Chapter6/Ch_6_28.htm) may be of interest.

Comment: OP, I hope you realise that so-called "numerology" is as true as astrology is, which is zero. Don't believe in this stuff. Whatever this "copper number square" is, it's all just a bunch of ordinary numbers, nothing "magical" or any claims of the sort, not at all. Don't believe this stuff, especially "mystics" who I can assure you are just fraudulent, they cannot "predict the future" or do anything that you might see in the movies.

Comment: The only puzzle here I don't get is how on Earth such a post receive so many upvotes?

Comment: If it helps anyone, [here is some information about the number 73](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/73_(number)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you got something that looks like this.

> [image: Kuber Yantra]

This is referred as

> '[Yantras](https://en.vedicencyclopedia.org/wiki/Numerical_Yantras)' In Hinduism

They are mathematical representation of

> Planetary Positions In Cosmic Houses

Mostly number adds up to

> [72](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/72_(number))

Since it was given by a Sufi mystic, I guess it represents

> [73 sects in Islam](http://www.ummah.com/forum/showthread.php?53514-73-Sects-of-Islam)

Comment: This is exactly what it looks like, except they are the digits drawn in my post. Thank you for your clarification, I was always interested in its meaning as it was not really explained to me, just given in passing. I wonder why one would go through the trouble of representing the varying sects of Islam as nine different numbers, but it is the most plausible answer that I have heard thus far. Thanks again.